# Pandas dataframe long to wide grouping by column with duplicated element

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hello I imported a dataframe which has no headers.
I created some headers using

```
df=pd.read_csv(path, names=['Prim Index', 'Alt Index', 'Aka', 'Name', 'Unnamed9'])
```

Then, I only keep

```
df=df[['Prim Index', 'Name']]
```

My question is how do I make df from long to wide, as 'Prim Index' is duplicated, I would like to have each unique Prim Index in one row and their names in different columns.

Thanks in advance! I appreciate any help on this!

Current df

```
Prim Index     Alt Index     Aka     Name         Unnamed9
1               2345         aka     Marcus           0
1               7634         aka     Tiffany          0
1               3242         aka     Royce            0
2               8765         aka     Charlotte        0
2               4343         aka     Sara             0
3               9825         aka     Keith            0
4               6714         aka     Jennifer         0
5               7875         aka     Justin           0
5               1345         aka     Diana            0
6               6591         aka     Liz              0
```

Desired df

```
Prim Index     Name1      Name2      Name3      Name4
1              Marcus    Tiffany     Royce
2             Charlotte   Sara
3              Keith
4             Jennifer
5              Justin     Diana
6              Liz
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you for your comment, just added a sample current and desired df

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex`, then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Prim Index', df.groupby('Prim Index').cumcount().add(1)])['Name']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .add_prefix('Name'))
print (df1)
                Name1    Name2  Name3
Prim Index                           
1              Marcus  Tiffany  Royce
2           Charlotte     Sara       
3               Keith                
4            Jennifer                
5              Justin    Diana       
6                 Liz
```

If there hast to be always 4 names add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `range`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['Prim Index', df.groupby('Prim Index').cumcount().add(1)])['Name']
         .unstack(fill_value='')
         .reindex(range(1, 5), fill_value='', axis=1)
         .add_prefix('Name'))
print (df1)
                Name1    Name2  Name3 Name4
Prim Index                                 
1              Marcus  Tiffany  Royce      
2           Charlotte     Sara             
3               Keith                      
4            Jennifer                      
5              Justin    Diana             
6                 Liz
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot Table, you can get similar solution that @jezreal did.

```
c = ['Prim Index','Name']
d = [[1,'Marcus'],[1,'Tiffany'],[1,'Royce'],
    [2,'Charlotte'],[2,'Sara'],
    [3,'Keith'],
    [4,'Jennifer'],
    [5,'Justin'],
    [5,'Diana'],
    [6,'Liz']]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d,columns=c)
print (df)
df=(pd.pivot_table(df,index='Prim Index',
                  columns=df.groupby('Prim Index').cumcount().add(1),values='Name',aggfunc='sum',fill_value='')
     .add_prefix('Name'))             
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
```

output of this will be:

```
   Prim Index      Name1    Name2  Name3
0           1     Marcus  Tiffany  Royce
1           2  Charlotte     Sara       
2           3      Keith                
3           4   Jennifer                
4           5     Justin    Diana       
5           6        Liz
```